# android - more button in tabbar

Tags: android, button, tabbar

is there any way to create ios like more button in android ?

here is some examples in ios.

http://docs.xamarin.com/static/recipes/ios/content_controls/tab_bar/specify_customizable_tab_bar_buttons/Images/Picture_1.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNpMh.png

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should stick to the user interface guidelines of android and not try to copy functionality of iOS. Android users expect their apps to work in certain ways, which often differ from the way iOS apps may work.
So stick to the Android ways -- it makes coding a lot easier and your users happy.